# How to use default modules like M2_1 MUX or FD flipflop in xilinx verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am able to use these default modules in **xilinx schematic** like *M2_1 MUX, FD flipflop* etc.

In **verilo**g I can able to use only **elementary gates** like *and, or ,not,xor* etc.

But **can I use these built-in Multiplexer (M2_1) or Flipflop(FD) in verilog?**, because if I use behavioral code, there may be poor synthesis in synopsis or xilinx for some cases. Also I want to use system level design.

Please help me to solve this issue. **Do I need to include any library to access this(built-in gates)?**

Please provide me example codes. I want ***direct instantiation*** of these(Mux and Flipflop) in **verilog** just as ***and, or*** etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use them in verilog. Xilinx provides user guides for how to do it [(example for 7 series here)](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2012_2/ug953-vivado-7series-libraries.pdf)

The user guide that I've given link to provides an example for FDCE flip flop such as (page 131):

```
// FDCE:Single Data Rate D Flip-Flop with Asynchronous Clear and
// Clock Enable (posedge clk).
// 7 Series
// Xilinx HDL Libraries Guide, version 2012.2 
FDCE #(
    .INIT(1'b0)
    // Initial value of register (1'b0 or 1'b1)
)
FDCE_inst
(
    .Q(Q),
    // 1-bit Data output
    .C(C),
    // 1-bit Clock input
    .CE(CE),
    // 1-bit Clock enable input
    .CLR(CLR),
    // 1-bit Asynchronous clear input
    .D(D)
    // 1-bit Data input 
);
// End of FDCE_inst instantiation
```

Comment: thanks it is a great help. And what about MUX. Do we have to make it by elementary gates or we can instantiate it like that like that.

Comment: For multiplexer the document gives MUXF7 primitive with LUT-type multiplexer such as `MUXF7 MUXF7_inst ( .O(O), //Output of MUX to general routing 
.I0(I0), // Input (tie to LUT6 O6 pin)
.I1(I1), // Input (tie to LUT6 O6 pin)
.S(S) // Input select to MUX
);` . But I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.